# Hacer URL amigable con .htaccess

Tags: web, .htaccess

anteriormente hice un post preguntando esto mismo, pero no me funcionaron los casos que me pusieron y prefiero ademas ser mas concreto y que me ayuden si puede ser.

Quiero hacer las URL de mi web amigables, pero concretamente que sea de la siguiente manera:
**www.miweb.net/ejemplo.html** a **www.miweb.net/ejemplo**

**www.miweb.net/ejemplo2.php** a **www.miweb.net/ejemplo2**

Tambien, si puede ser, darme la opcion de poder añadir carpetas a la URL, como si quedara **www.miweb.net/carpeta/ejemplo**.

Actualmente lo tengo asi el archivo y me sale en apache un error:
500 Internal Server Error

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo este código y funciona correctamente en codeigniter 3.1.9

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|fontawesome-5.3.1-web|fonts|js|images|robots.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cecytem/index.php/$1 [L]
```

El siguiente fragmento de código es donde van tus carpetas para acceder:

```
(index.php|css|fontawesome-5.3.1-web|fonts|js|images|robots.txt)
```